# How to add single if statement in flask

Tags: python-3.x, templates, flask

I am using Python 3.5 to develop a web app with Flask.
Having the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html', show_hidden=False)

app.run()
```

and the template `main.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hey!</h1>
    {% if show_hidden == True %}
        <p>Hidden text</p>
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now this seems an unuseful feature, but I'll find a way to determine whether the hidden text should be displayed.

When the above code runs, the hidden text is shown although `show_hidden` is set to False. Furthermore, when it is turned to True the hidden text is displayed twice. As I have followed the docs this code is supposed to be working. Could someone please point me out what am I missing?

Comment: Simply print show_hidden using {{ show_hidden }} somewhere in your html and see what are you getting.

Answer (score 4):

The `== True` is redundant, you can just check whether `{% if show_hidden %}`

Change :

```
{% if show_hidden == True %}
```

To :

```
{% if show_hidden %}
```

Comment: Also, maybe use javascript to enable and disable the hidden text. You can pass variables from python to javascript functions as well.

Comment: Hmm, seems like I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'` error, and the docs actually say the way I am doing it works

Comment: @jameskaly , Sorry.. I confused, try the code I've edited now.

Comment: Doesnt make a difference to my example though, still getting same output

Comment: Nope, still stays there! I dont think its being passed as a string, since when I set `show_hidden` to `True` its being displayed once more, so the code knows when to add it.

Comment: Is it possible that somewhere else in your code you render this template with parameter True?

Comment: Nope. Nowhere else

Comment: @jameskaly , I've made a project [here](http://code.runnable.com/WKMp6yx-YjYaycL2/testso-for-python-flask-and-jinja2) with the same logic as you have and it's working fine with the flag True or False. please check and try to compare to yours.